# c# creating DB from code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My program keeps crashing when I am trying to add from code Person details,name in this example

Take a look at my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new PersonContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new Person 
                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Person Name: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();
                //Adding new person to the DB
                var person = new Person { Name = name };
                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from p in db.Persons
                            orderby p.Name
                            select p;

                Console.WriteLine("All persons in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int NameId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    }



    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When it reach this line:

```
            db.Persons.Add(person);
```

it crash, complaining that the person does not have an id, but even if I give it direct ID number it does not help me resolve the issue.
Looking at the debug I see it gets ID 0 so I am not sure this is actually the problem.
I took the sample code from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

And customize it to my own needs.
Any idea?

Comment: by the sounds of it then your ID isnt auto incrementing.. and you've said it doesnt help if you provide one, but havent said why not..

Comment: Just curious, why the property `Persons` is virtual in `Person`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create table in SQL? If not you can inside DBContext put this:

```
        public DataContext() : base("Empirium")
    {
        // Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

After that, check function Add,...